# Adding rows with default values if condition is null

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to add rows with default values if some field is null.

Imagine the following SELECT clause:

```
SELECT date, id, name, COALESCE(value1, -1), COALESCE(value2, -1), 
COALESCE(value3, -1) 
FROM (SELECT DATE("startDate" + INTERVAL(seq_ref.seq - 1) MONTH) AS month_ref 
FROM (SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_36) seq_ref, table) table
WHERE...
```

And the following dataset:

```
date        id   name       value1 value2 value3
2016-01-01  1    TEST LEFT  12     14     22
2016-01-01  1    TEST RIGHT 32     11     74
2016-02-01  1    null       -1     -1     -1
2016-03-01  1    TEST LEFT  09     66     33
2016-03-01  1    TEST RIGHT 13     41     20
```

OK so basically it returns some data in a date range. But if some months don't have data, returns -1 for values.
I need to know if there's a way to add two rows with default values for id and name if has no data.

For example: on `2016-02-01` I should be able to show a row for `TEST LEFT` with -1 to values and `TEST RIGHT` with -1 to values.

**EDIT**: Result should be something like

```
date        id   name       value1 value2 value3
2016-01-01  1    TEST LEFT  12     14     22
2016-01-01  1    TEST RIGHT 32     11     74
2016-02-01  1    TEST LEFT  -1     -1     -1
2016-02-01  1    TEST RIGHT -1     -1     -1
2016-03-01  1    TEST LEFT  09     66     33
2016-03-01  1    TEST RIGHT 13     41     20
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IFNULL() function. 
It works like so: IFNULL(expression, value) 
where it checks if expression is null and if it is, it replaces it with the value parameter 
You could probably do something like:

```
    SELECT date, id, name, IFNULL(value1, -1), IFNULL(value2, -1), 
IFNULL(value3, -1) 
FROM (SELECT DATE("startDate" + INTERVAL(seq_ref.seq - 1) MONTH) AS month_ref 
FROM (SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_36) seq_ref, table) table
WHERE...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But I need to provide different values for name. I have edited the post.

Comment: Do you mean that name has to be -1 if it is null as well? 
If so you could probably do something like: 

     IFNULL(name, "TEST LEFT") 

Is there any way to know if it should insert TEST LEFT or TEST RIGHT ? 

Otherwise you could probably use a TRIGGER, which is triggered if something is null and then calls ALTER TABLE